# Change template for 2columns-left.phtml on Fishpig Wordpress pages

Tags: layout, magento-1, template, third-party-module, wordpress

I'm trying to change the template used by fishpig to use a custom **wp-2columns-left.phtml** template.

I've tried updating my theme's **local.xml** file with:

```
<wordpress_default>
    <reference name="root">
          <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/wp-2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</wordpress_default>
```

I've also tried amending the **wordpress.xml** to use the same template but it doesn't work either.

I thought that maybe the **wordpress_default** layout handle was incorrect but I tested it by removing some js from the head and found it worked.

```
<wordpress_default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><script>fishpig/wordpress/search.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</wordpress_default>
```

Am I missing something?  Could something else be overwriting this layout xml?  In my theme only **wordpress.xml** & **local.xml** are using the **wordpress_default** handle.

I'm using the ultimo magento theme and the cache is disabled.

Comment: Please try flushing the cache... it seems to be the caching issue

Comment: @Dexter caching was disabled, I flushed the cache anyway but no change :(

Comment: The code you used to change template layout is correct... moreover you can give a try setting the template code in wordpress.xml

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to change the default layout template via backend?
Wordpress > settings > Template

It is saved in your DB under the core_config table.

To control the layout via XML you need to select  -- Default template -- and this will read the value in your XML file

Comment: I tried this but if I select the _-- Default --_ Template it uses the template selected in the Default field.  If I set the Default field to _-- Default --_ template, no template is loaded.  I think this must be what is overriding to local.xml though